# Python & Pyqt5 : Create Button After a File Exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, listener

I'm trying to build a simple application using Pyqt5. My purpose is, when I click `Listen` button, open my another exe (built from another platform) and checks every second that `a.txt` exists or not. If exists; I want to create a new button on current interface.

Now, when I click Listen button, I can open my other exe (I will use `notepad` in here for minimal example) and my application starts always checking the `a.txt` exists. After few seconds, I'm creating `a.txt` from another script. My problem is; new button does not appear. But if I close empty notepad, new button appears.

My script for simple interface:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
import time
import subprocess
import os

class ListenWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListenWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Listen")

        self.button_login = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Listen', self)
        font3 = self.button_login.font()  # lineedit current font
        font3.setPointSize(10)  # change it's size
        self.button_login.setFont(font3)
        self.button_login.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.button_login.clicked.connect(self.startToListen)

        self.v_box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_box1.addWidget(self.button_login)

        self.h_box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_box1.addLayout(self.h_box1)

    def startToListen(self):
        FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        args = "notepad"
        subprocess.call(args, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=False)

        while not os.path.exists('C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/abc/a.txt'):
            time.sleep(1)

        if os.path.isfile('C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/abc/a.txt'):
            self.buttonSeq = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start Sequence', self)
            font8 = self.buttonSeq.font()  # lineedit current font
            font8.setPointSize(10)  # change it's size
            self.buttonSeq.setFont(font8)
            self.buttonSeq.setFixedSize(200, 50)
            self.h_box1.addWidget(self.buttonSeq, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        else:
            raise ValueError("%s isn't a file!" % 'C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/abc/a.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ListenWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Login')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My script for creating `a.txt` file:

```
f=open("a.txt", "a+")
for i in range(2):
     f.write("Appended line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
f.close()
```

Where is my fault? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to open the program with `subprocess.call()`. Don't use `call()` it will wait for the process to complete.

Use the [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), if you don't want to wait:

```
subprocess.Popen(["notepad"], stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
```

or simply use the os.startfile:

```
os.startfile("C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe")
```